# Pixel image background size Sprite Kit Game

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I develop Sprite kit game. I want to use pixel art in my project, and I am looking for a best way to use pixel images in my game. There is a complicated background image in this project
Should I draw differebt backgrounds for any iPhone screen sizes. Or there is a way to draw only three background images(1x, 2x, 3x) like in non pixel art images. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Texture Atlas](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktextureatlas) for all your images, including backgrounds. The easiest way to do that is within your XCAssets catalogue in XCode, as described in the linked documentation.

This will allow you to define 1x, 2x and 3x versions of your images. Whether doing that is strictly necessary or not depends on how you are going to scale your scene on different devices. See [this discussion](https://spritekitlessons.com/what-size-to-make-your-skscene-image-sizes-in-sprite-kit/) for why you may want to stick to just a high resolution image in the 1x slot.

Comment: 2x is for devices with this resolutions:750x1334, 640x1136, 640x960
But in assets catalog I can add only one image
In this case what resolution and scales of pixel art background should be for 2x and 3x?

Comment: @ДаняКравчук If you create a Texture Atlas / Sprite Atlas as described in the documentation I linked you can add 1x, 2x and 3x images for each texture, if that fits your needs.